# c++ extern string array not visible

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ development , As I learn online about extern variable - I tried it to string variables and its working fine.But I have to work with string variable as its not working.Please look as follow.

**globals.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SIMULATIONFILEPARSER_GLOBALS_H
#define SIMULATIONFILEPARSER_GLOBALS_H
//sequence of files to be execute
extern string ipFiles[];
#endif //SIMULATIONFILEPARSER_GLOBALS_H
```

**globals.cpp**

```
#include "../headers/globals.h"
//sequence of files to be execute
string ipFiles[] = {"in.relaxSubstrate", "in.relaxFluid"};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Source/headers/globals.h"

int main() {
    for (string &ipFileName :ipFiles) {
        std::cout << ipFileName << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this project , It gives following error

```
C:\Users\king\ClionProjects\SimulationFileParser\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\king\ClionProjects\SimulationFileParser\main.cpp:5:30: error: range-based 'for' expression of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> []' has incomplete type
     for (string &ipFileName :ipFiles) {
                              ^
CMakeFiles\SimulationFileParser.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SimulationFileParser.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [SimulationFileParser] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'SimulationFileParser' failed
```

Comment: #include <string> wherever you use it.

Comment: And don't use `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: I am working with string array, i included but it still giving same error

Comment: The compiler isn't complaining, that the symbol isn't visible. It's telling you, that it doesn't know it's complete type. All it sees is an array of **unknown** size. It cannot possible construct a range-based for loop over an unknown type.

Comment: removed 'using namespace std;' but still no success

Comment: I think this problem would be solved by using a `std::array` instead of a a raw array. :)

Comment: I suggest you use a `std::vector` for this unless you are okay with hard coding the size of the array in the header file.

Comment: @IInspectable so what should I do ?

Comment: *"what should I do ?"* - Use `extern vector<string> ipFiles;` or `extern list<string> ipFiles;`. Both are complete types and allow the compiler to implement a range-based for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't complain about a symbol, that's not visible. It's telling you, that the type is incomplete:

> range-based 'for' expression of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string []' **has incomplete type**

Until the compiler knows the size of the array, it cannot compile the range-based for loop. To change this, you need to declare a complete type. This could be an array with an explicit size, or - and that's the recommended solution - a standard container<sup>1</sup>:

**globals.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<std::string> ipFiles;
```

**globals.cpp**

```
std::vector<std::string> ipFiles{"in.relaxSubstrate", "in.relaxFluid"};
```

You don't have to change *main.cpp*. But if you want to make it fancy, you could use `auto` as well as exercising const-correctness:

```
int main() {
    for (const auto& ipFileName : ipFiles) {
        std::cout << ipFileName << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *The size of a standard container does not need to be known at compile time. All the compiler needs are the (forward) iterators to `begin()` and `end()` of the controlled sequence. An array, on the other hand, doesn't provide those as member functions, and the compiler needs to generate them. It needs to know the size to generate the equivalent of `end()`.*

Answer (score 0):

This loop does not know the size of array.

```
for (string &ipFileName :ipFiles)
```

Change in global.h

```
extern string ipFiles[2];
```

change in global.cpp

```
string ipFiles[2] = {"in.relaxSubstrate", "in.relaxFluid"};
```

After this your code should compile properly.

Comment: @ErKandarpPatel Please check the answer by IInspectable.that is a better approach. My answer just solve your problem. But its not good practice.